# How to sign kernel module from kernel source file?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, embedded-linux

I am investigating signing kernel module from kernel source file in android open source project. I don't know how do it. How can I do it?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: There's `sign-file` in `scripts/` directory in Linux source. All details are in Documentation/module-signing.txt: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/module-signing.txt?id=refs/tags/v4.9-rc3

Comment: http://chrisarges.net/2016/03/25/signed-kernel-modules-using-an-auxiliary-key.html 
Kernel signing was explained clearly above link.

Answer (score 0):

There's `sign-file` in `scripts/` directory in Linux source. All details are in [Documentation/module-signing.txt](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/module-signing.txt?id=refs/tags/v4.9-rc3). Basically once you've generated signing keys using section GENERATING SIGNING KEYS in the document, run `scripts/sign-file sha512 kernel-signkey.priv kernel-signkey.x509 module.ko` as decribed under section MANUALLY SIGNING MODULES.